# How to only get one value of child firebase cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to send notifications that trigger into pengumuman topic.

```
export const onNotifPengumuman = functions.database.ref('/pengumuman_course/{course_id_p}/{pengumuman_id}')
.onCreate((snapshot,context) =>{


    const course_id_p = context.params.course_id_p;
    const pengumuman_id = context.params.pengumuman_id;



    const nama_matkul = admin.database().ref('/courses/'+course_id_p+'name').once('value').then(snap =>{

        return snapshot.val();

        }).catch(error =>
             {
        console.log(error);
    })

    console.log(`cobacobacoba ${nama_matkul}`);

    return admin.database().ref('pengumuman/' + pengumuman_id + '/').once('value').then(snap =>{
        const pengumumanData = snap.val();
        const notifDataPengumuman = {
            data:{
                data_type: "pengumuman ",
                title: "Pengumuman Baru", // data bebas (key, value)
                body: `${nama_matkul}`, // chatId = const chatId
                sound: "default"
            }
        }
        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(course_id_p, notifDataPengumuman) 

            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
              })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
              });


    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })

});
```

In the first ref `functions.database.ref('/pengumuman_course/{course_id_p}/{pengumuman_id}')` I want to access and trigger this child in firebase real time database, the code below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4zwP.png)

after that in this code `return admin.database().ref('pengumuman/' + pengumuman_id + '/')` I'm tring to get all of information about pengumuman and send it into users. The code in below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eBX1.png)

But before that I want to get `pengumuman` name in the courses ref in the database to get value of name ,with this code :

```
 const nama_matkul = admin.database().ref('/courses/'+course_id_p+'name').once('value').then(snap =>{

        return snapshot.val();

        }).catch(error =>
             {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htggg.png)

The problem is when I'm using that code to get child name and store it into matkul, when I send/log ,it will return promises object. I want the result showing "REKAYASA PERANGKAT LUNAK".
Thanks and sorry for bad explanation

[FIXED]

Im trying the solution and found this code

```
export const onNotifPengumuman = functions.database.ref('/pengumuman_course/{course_id_p}/{pengumuman_id}')
.onCreate((snapshot,context) =>{


    const course_id_p = context.params.course_id_p;
    console.log(`course id pengumuman ${course_id_p}`);
    const pengumuman_id = context.params.pengumuman_id;

    admin.database().ref('/courses/' + course_id_p + '/').once('value').then(snap2 =>{
        const nama_matkul = snap2.child('name').val();

        console.log(`nama matkul dari sini ${nama_matkul}`);

        admin.database().ref('pengumuman/' + pengumuman_id + '/').once('value').then(snap =>{
            const pengumumanData = snap.val();
            const notifDataPengumuman = {
                data:{
                    data_type: "pengumuman",
                    title: "Pengumuman Baru", // data bebas (key, value)
                    body: `Judul :${nama_matkul}`, // chatId = const chatId
                    sound: "default"
                }
            }
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(course_id_p, notifDataPengumuman) 

                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                  })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                  });


        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
    })



});
```

Comment: try `ref('/courses/{courseId}/name')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to resolve promises in order to get the value returned by them. What you are doing at the moment is assigning `nama_matkul` the promise but you never wait for it to complete.

**Async/Await**
You can either use `async`/`await` by defining your function as asynchronous:

```
.onCreate(async (snapshot,context) =>{
  // Your asynchronous code here
}
```

You can then resolve the promise by running 
    const nama_matkul = (await admin.database().ref('/courses/'+course_id_p+'name').once('value')).val();

If you need to handle exceptions, wrap the promise and await in a try catch block.

After refactoring your code, it might look something like this:

```
export const onNotifPengumuman = functions.database.ref('/pengumuman_course/{course_id_p}/{pengumuman_id}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot,context) => {
  try {
    const course_id_p = context.params.course_id_p;
    const pengumuman_id = context.params.pengumuman_id;
    const nama_matkul = (await admin.database().ref('/courses/'+course_id_p+'name').once('value')).val();
    console.log(`cobacobacoba ${nama_matkul}`);

    const pengumumanData = (await admin.database().ref('pengumuman/' + pengumuman_id + '/').once('value')).val();
    const notifDataPengumuman = {
        data: {
            data_type: "pengumuman ",
            title: "Pengumuman Baru", // data bebas (key, value)
            body: `${nama_matkul}`, // chatId = const chatId
            sound: "default"
        }
    }
    try {
      await admin.messaging().sendToTopic(course_id_p, notifDataPengumuman);
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    } catch (messageSendError) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", messageSendError);
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

});
```

**Then/Catch**

If you do want to stick with the current setup you have and work with callbacks, you can instead keep the `.then` call and handle your application logic in the callback; your code might look something like this:

```
export const onNotifPengumuman = functions.database.ref('/pengumuman_course/{course_id_p}/{pengumuman_id}')
.onCreate((snapshot,context) => {
    const course_id_p = context.params.course_id_p;
    const pengumuman_id = context.params.pengumuman_id;
    admin.database().ref('/courses/'+course_id_p+'name').once('value')
      .then(nameSnapshot => {
        const nama_matkul = nameSnapshot.val();

        console.log(`cobacobacoba ${nama_matkul}`);
        admin.database().ref('pengumuman/' + pengumuman_id + '/').once('value')
          .then(dataSnapshot => {
            const pengumumanData = dataSnapshot.val();
            const notifDataPengumuman = {
                data: {
                    data_type: "pengumuman ",
                    title: "Pengumuman Baru", // data bebas (key, value)
                    body: `${nama_matkul}`, // chatId = const chatId
                    sound: "default"
                }
            }
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(course_id_p, notifDataPengumuman)
              .then(response => console.log("Successfully sent message:", response))
              .catch(error => console.log("Error sending message:", error));
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))


});
```

You can of course use a combination of then/catch and await if you so wish, whether this is a good practice or when to use which really depends on the situation in which you use it.

Comment: Sir, im trying to following ur 2nd option. But the nama_matkul is null. What happen?

Comment: Hey, I've fixed the issues in my code. I had wrongly named two of the variables. Regard the line `.then(nameSnapshot => {` and the line `const nama_matkul = nameSnapshot.val();`. I hope this helps.